# How to create an event listener using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery. I know this question is a little bit confusing but, maybe this explanation might help:

I have a dynamic `<li>` tag generated by JavaScript with dynamic Id's, I just want to add an event listener to every new generated `<li>` tag. Maybe in a way like this ? I know this doesn't work.

```
<li id="2" onadded="createEvent()"></li> //new generated <li> tag
<li id="1" onadded="createEvent()"></li> //the 1st generated <li> tag

<script>
function createEvent(){
  //event here
}
</script>
```

How can I achieved that ? or any possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using $.fn.on function to bind event for parent of li , and use selector "li" for li, then your dynamic generated li elment will reponse the event. Like following:

```
    //$(document) can be replaced  by $(parentsOfLi) , .i.e: $("ul")  or $("#" + idOful)
$(document).on("click", "li", function () {
    //do your process here
    //alert($(this).text());
    //$(this).parent().append("<li></li>")
})
```